# Use a function in the groupby clause of a functional select

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Is it possible to include a function in the groupby section of functional select, similar to how the aggregations work?

For example how would I turn

```
select by `long$`timespan$04:00 xbar time from table
```

into functional select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Yes you can, just function should be allowed/compatible to group by clause. 'xbar' is allowed.

Syntax is: (function;param1;parma2;...param n)

Here is one ex.

```
          q)t:([]id:til 20;v:til 20)
          q)select by 5 xbar id from t
          q) // functional form
          q)?[`t;();(enlist `id)!enlist (xbar;5;`id);()]
```

**2. Trick to get functional form of simple query :**
Use 'parse' function:

```
           q) parse "select id from t"
```

output is functional form :

```
           q)(?;`t;,(),0b,(,`id)!,`id)
```

use it to make functional form:

```
           q) ?[`t;();0b;(enlist `id)!enlist `id]
```

**3.** Functional form of your query using 'parse' is:

```
q)?[`table;();(enlist `time)!enlist ($;enlist `long;($;enlist `timespan;(xbar;04:00;`time)));()
```

Answer (score 1):

For something that is as complex as this, I'd just put the `xbar` part into a functionn:

```
?[`table;();(1#`time)!enlist({(`long$`timespan$04:00) xbar x};`time);()]
```